# How to deserialize an item into different types? (Newtonsoft, C#, .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, json, jsonconverter

I'm getting a json message with a field called `"item"` that can be deserialized as class foo or class bar.
How do I implement this in C#?

I assume something like this:

```
public class FooOrBar 
{
     // Only one of the two will get populated.
     public Foo foo { get; set; }
     public Bar bar { get; set; }
     bool is_foo;
}

[JsonProperty("item")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
public FooOrBar Item { get; set; }
```

How do I implement the custom converter for such a case?

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: please can you add your json to your post to be more helpful

Comment: Something like: root_message could either be  { "item": { ...foo entries... } or  { "item": { ...bar entries...} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how `Foo` or `Bar` is determined in your code, but for now let's assume you have a JSON structure like this:

```
var json = @"
{
  isFoo: true,
  item: {}
}";
```

In which case `Foo` or `Bar` is determined by `isFoo`.

`FooOrBar` class could be subjective. I would not define class like that, but use polymorphism:

```
interface IItem
{
    bool IsFoo { get; }
}

class Foo : IItem
{
    public bool IsFoo => true;
}

class Bar : IItem
{
    public bool IsFoo => false;
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]
class MyClass
{
    public IItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

I set `CustomJsonConverter` to `MyClass` because of the JSON structure I have. I need to use information available in the parent object of `item` to determine `Foo` or `Bar` so I have to set `JsonConverter` to the declaring type of `Item` property. If you use information available in `item` property, you can move converter to the `Item` property.

Now implement `CustomJsonConverter` like this:

```
class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Create an instance of MyClass, and set property as per "isFoo".
        var obj = new MyClass();        

        if (token["isFoo"].Value<bool>())
        {
            obj.Item = new Foo();
        }
        else
        {
            obj.Item = new Bar();
        }

        // Populate properties
        serializer.Populate(token.CreateReader(), obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```